# How to develop Custom Action on Bot Framework v2.0

Tags: botframework, custom-action, bot-framework-composer

Could someone please help with how to enable / develop custom action with latest preview / 2.0 version of Bot Framweork.  The microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action?tabs=csharp) only seems to work for v1.4.1

Thanks

Comment: I guess you really mean Bot Framework Composer, right?

Comment: Please keep an eye on this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/7829). There is not any directions on how to accomplish this for 2.0 (as it is still preview), but I will post steps if I can get it working.

Answer (score 4):

So, BotComponents are the new route for custom actions. Please follow the directions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/blob/main/docs/extending-with-code.md). The two things you will likely have to change are:

- Update/add a newer package for `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core`. I went with `3.0.5` for both projects.
- Use `"components":[{"name":"MultiplyDialog"}]` instead of `"components":[{"name":"CustomAction.MultiplyDialog"}]`.

On point #2, I was getting a build error (`FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CustomAction.MultiplyDialog`) and thefore did the above to resolve. Odd thing here is that once I was able to build in VS, then run and test in Composer, it's once again back to `CustomAction.MultiplyDialog`, but it works.

This documenation should make it's way to the Composer documentation once `2.0` is released.

Comment: Thank you! Changing CustomAction.MultiplyDialog to MultiplyDialog did the trick for me. I never would have figured this out on my own

Answer (score 0):

Please find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions).

- Add a new project named MultiplyDialog to your solution. In Visual
  Studio right-click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and
  select Add > New Project. Use the Class Library project template.

  - Add a reference to the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Adaptive.Runtime
    package. Use the same version as the bot depends on.
  - Add a project reference from the bot project to the component
    project. Right-click on the  project and select Add > Project
    Reference. Choose the MultiplyDialog project and click OK.
  - Build the entire solution to restore all packages and validate the
    dependency tree.

**Create the custom action**

Actions in Composer are special implementations of the Dialog base class. This allows each action in the trigger to be pushed onto the dialog stack, and executed in turn.

In the new project, rename the Class1.cs file to MultiplyDialog.cs, and update it's contents to look like the below:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AdaptiveExpressions.Properties;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MultiplyDialog : Dialog
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public MultiplyDialog([CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
        : base()
    {
        // enable instances of this command as debug break point
        RegisterSourceLocation(sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);
    }

    [JsonProperty("$kind")]
    public const string Kind = "MultiplyDialog";

    [JsonProperty("arg1")]
    public NumberExpression Arg1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("arg2")]
    public NumberExpression Arg2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resultProperty")]
    public StringExpression ResultProperty { get; set; }

    public override Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var arg1 = Arg1.GetValue(dc.State);
        var arg2 = Arg2.GetValue(dc.State);

        var result = Convert.ToInt32(arg1) * Convert.ToInt32(arg2);
        if (this.ResultProperty != null)
        {
            dc.State.SetValue(this.ResultProperty.GetValue(dc.State), result);
        }

        return dc.EndDialogAsync(result: result, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**Create the schema file**

The .schema file for the component is a partial schema that will be merged into the main .schema file for the bot. Although it is possible to edit the main sdk.schema file for the bot directly, doing so is not recommended. Merging partial schema files will isolate changes, allow for easier recovery from errors, and enable easier packaging of your component for reuse.

Create a new file in the project named MultiplyDialog.schema and update the contents to the below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.botframework.com/schemas/component/v1.0/component.schema",
    "$role": "implements(Microsoft.IDialog)",
    "title": "Multiply",
    "description": "This will return the result of arg1*arg2",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "arg1": {
            "$ref": "schema:#/definitions/integerExpression",
            "title": "Arg1",
            "description": "Value from callers memory to use as arg 1"
        },
        "arg2": {
            "$ref": "schema:#/definitions/integerExpression",
            "title": "Arg2",
            "description": "Value from callers memory to use as arg 2"
        },
        "resultProperty": {
            "$ref": "schema:#/definitions/stringExpression",
            "title": "Result",
            "description": "Value from callers memory to store the result"
        }
    }
}
```

**Create the BotComponent class**

The adaptive runtime will dynamically discover and inject components at startup time.

Create a new MultiplyDialogBotComponent.cs file in the project and update the contents to

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class MultiplyDialogBotComponent : BotComponent
{
     public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         // Anything that could be done in Startup.ConfigureServices can be done here.
         // In this case, the MultiplyDialog needs to be added as a new DeclarativeType.
         services.AddSingleton<DeclarativeType>(sp => new DeclarativeType<MultiplyDialog>(MultiplyDialog.Kind));
     }
}
```

In the appsettings.json file of the bot project (located at \settings)to include the MultiplyDialogBotComponent in the runtimeSettings/components array.

```
"runtimeSettings": {
   "components": [
      {
         "name": "MultiplyDialog"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Merge schema files**

The final step is to merge the partial schema file from the MultiplyDialog project into the main sdk.schema file for the bot. This makes the custom action available for use in Composer.

Navigate to the schemas folder in the myBot project. This folder contains a PowerShell script and a bash script. Use an elevated PowerShell terminal to execute the PowerShell script. You will need to either copy/paste the contents of the script, or ensure your execution-policy allows for running unsigned scripts.

To validate the script executed successfully, search for MultiplyDialog inside the MyBot\schemas\sdk.schema file and validate that the partial schema from the MultiplyDialog.schema file is included in sdk.schema.